# Function with If/Else Statement - Comparing Dates

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am working with a function and I am trying to write an if-else statment that compares a textfield aganist some dates.

This is what my function looks like right now:

```
function updateSwitch(){
    if (effDate.getValue() > effDate.getValue(new Date())){
         submitButton.disable();
    }
    else{
       submitButton.enable();
    }
}
```

I am trying to compare the dates among the same textfield. I am trying to say that if the date enetered in the textfield is in the future (any day after tomorrow), then disable the submitButton. I know that 
the function works if I compare the textfield aganist a different textfield, but I cannot get it to work within the same textfield.

Comment: Normally you'd convert the text date to a date and then compare that to a date. Comparing them as strings is liable to go well wrong eg. 21/2/2012 > 1/3/2013 ...

Comment: So what does `getValue`, `enable` etc do, and how are you getting those dates ?

Comment: Those .getValue are being populated with dates automatically and the .enable is just enabling or disabling the submit button action

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have your dates constructed. Is `effdate` been constructed with the `Date` object? If so, may I suggest using [`valueOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp). It'll return the primitive value - or the date in milliseconds. This should allow for a more consistent comparison.

```
function updateSwitch(date){
    var effDate = Date.parse(date);
    var curDate = new Date();
    if (effDate.valueOf() > curDate){
       submitButton.disable();
    }
    else{
       submitButton.enable();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using getValue() because EXTJS 4.1 does not handle the ValueOf() method.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't support it? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Date-method-valueOf

Comment: Their docs say they've supported it for awhile. "Available since: 4.0.0". See the link I sent you before.